# Как исправить ошибку с записью русских букв на C++?

Tags: c++, кодировка

Вообщем, все максимально просто.

Английский текст вставляется нормально, а вот русский выглядит так: **ЇЁиЁ**

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: В скобочках замечу, что это не ошибка в C++, а специфическая особенность Windows (она до сих пор использует однобайтовые кодировки, но, мало того, в GUI и в консоли она их для русского использует РАЗНЫЕ!. На других системах такого эффекта не наблюдается. И ещё в скобках: обычно локализацию делают другими способами, а не прописыванием строк на неанглийских языках прямо в код.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, а если не трудно, подскажите как

Comment: В основном с помощью gettext, например, как описано в ответах с его упоминанием тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789615/how-to-support-multiple-language-in-a-linux-c-c-program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если просто `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus")` не помогло попробуйте подключить `#include <clocale>` и теперь уже ввести в `int main()` строку `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus")`

Answer (score 2):

В main строку добавьте
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
тогда будут корректно выводиться символы.

Comment: По умолчанию C++ работает с кодировкой ASCII которая не поддерживает русские символы, поэтому выводиться не корректно.

Comment: Не сработало, к сожалению